# how to set default application version in azure batch using java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-batch

Is there a way to set the default application version in azure batch account  using java sdk?
The sample script that they have in the git does not show how to set the default version(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-java-manage-batch-accounts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/batch/samples/ManageBatchAccount.java).

Also I was trying to dig in the interface(https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-batch/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/batch/Application.java) to get some clues but couldn't see anything that supports updating the default version.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get the version update working following @brklein suggestion:

```
BatchApplication batchApplication = batchAccount.applications().get(applicationName)
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(applicationId, tenantId, appSecret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE)
BatchManager batchManager = BatchManager.authenticate(credentials, subscriptionId)
ApplicationsInner applicationsInner = batchManager.inner().applications()
ApplicationUpdateParameters parameters = new ApplicationUpdateParameters(defaultVersion: DEFAULT_APP_VERSION)
applicationsInner.update(resourceGroupName, batchAccountName, batchApplication.id(), parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that default version is being surface at the client layer of the SDK.

To get around this you should be able to call the implementation methods manually, which have the full functionality of the REST API (as they are auto-generated).
To do this create either `CreateApplicationParameters` or `ApplicationUpdateParameters` and set the defaultVersion property. Then you can call the implementations create or update methods manually (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/78e8ff2940eba34bc63f8e7be6807a377500f5c7/azure-mgmt-batch/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/batch/implementation/ApplicationsInner.java#L474).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is really helpful. Is there a way to get the instance of AppliactionsInner without manually instantiating it? It seem like the only way to get it is via BatchManagementClientImpl<-BatchManager, but batchManager is private property in com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure.

Comment: I believe you will need to construct your own BatchManager, and then you should be able to get it from the accessor.